# Automatically sum up Table column named payments to a cell from another sheet without a cmd button

Tags: excel, vba, automation, calculated-columns

Is there a way to automatically run a vba code that I have written for a sheet without manually running the code via a cmd button or the run code option in vba editor

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()

Dim sumrange As Range
Dim Sumcolumn As Double

Set sumrange = Sheets("Receipt Input").Range("TBL_receipts[Payments]")
Sumcolumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sumrange)

Range("b3").Value = Sumcolumn

End Sub
```

This is the code I wrote

[image]

Above a screenshot of the error I get

Comment: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` - must be exactly that signature.  You can ignore `Target` in your code, but it must be present as a parameter.

Comment: thank u i tried it the error is not popping up anymore but the code is not running by itself as a loop. any ideas how to further?

Comment: Question is when should the code run? When you activate the sheet resp. deactivate it? Or when you change a value in a cell? Or when you change the selection? And why should the code run as a loop? Do you want to have an endless loop? Then you won't be able to interact with Excel anymore.

Comment: the code should run when a value is added to the last row of a table in another sheet named payments

Comment: Then you need to use the `Worksheet_Change` of that sheet to run the code. And, of course, you need to check if the cell that was changed is really on the last row of that very table. Anyway, that is a different question than the one you raised in your post.

Comment: and the `Range("b3").Value` need to be qualified with the other sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sub is in sheet where the table exists.
Change the "targetWorkSheet" to the real target sheet name where save the sum

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim sumrange As Range
   Dim Sumcolumn As Double
   Set sumrange = Me.Range("TBL_receipts[Payments]")
   If Not Intersect(Target, sumrange) Is Nothing Then
      Sumcolumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sumrange)
      'Application.EnableEvents = False
      Worksheets("targetWorkSheet").Range("B3").Value = Sumcolumn
      'Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Copy the sum at Worksheets("targetWorkSheet").Range("B3") only if sumrange changes.

Comment: very helpfull thank u was really pulling my hair